# How many positive integers $p$, $q$, $r$ exists?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many positive integers $p$, $q$, $r$ exists satisfying the relation below?

> $$p/q + q/r + r/p = 2$$

Thank in advance.
I tried so much but could not think how to proceed.

I just need a hint from where to begin.

Comment: The following link gives not any help to find the answer to the problem but shows a related number theoretic problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113546/solutions-of-q-fracxy-fracyz-fraczx-s-t-q-geq-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** : Note that from AM-GM inequality, we have that $a+b+c \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{abc}$. If you wish to view the answer, hover your cursor over the grey region directly below.

> **Answer**: Since $p$, $q$ and $r$ are positive, so are $\frac{p}{q}$, $\frac{q}{r}$, $\frac{r}{p}$. From AM-GM inequality, we have that $$\displaystyle \frac{p}{q} + \frac{q}{r} + \frac{r}{p} \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{\frac{p}{q} \times \frac{q}{r} \times \frac{r}{p}} = 3.$$ Hence, there doesn't exists any $p$, $q$ and $r$ satisfying $\displaystyle \frac{p}{q} + \frac{q}{r} + \frac{r}{p} = 2$.

Comment: Beat me to it by 30 seconds. :-) (I +1'd it. )

Comment: @Sivaram what if the condition of p,q,r being integer is removed.will the answer remains the same.

Comment: @vikiiii Yes. The proof only needs $a$,$b$,$c$ are positive.

Comment: @Sivaram : thanks.Idea of giving answer in grey region is awesum.

Comment: I got that idea from one of @KannappanSampath answers.